# Reading from and Sending data to Serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm trying to do a serial port communication to send and receive data. Here is the scenerio:

I connect to a serial port and start my device. When it's counting down to do something, I should pause it and send it some command to work. It does all work and then again the starting continues.

Now i searched through the internet and c# fits me. Can you suggest anything to me while doing this? How can i start and which methods do i need to use ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a detailed guide here [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/SerialPorts.aspx#) which covers good practise in using Serial Ports in C#.

Comment: I have not read that entire article, but I did find the section where the Write command is issued.  There is a serious problem with the SerialPort class that will drive a person mad if they are not aware of it.  SerialPort.Read and SerialPort.Write are not thread safe.  If you enter both at the same time, your object will go all kinds of crazy.  It doesn't happen that often because most serial protocols are rather low data rate, but when it does happen you are left scratching your head.  Putting a lock around your read and write statements is critical, even if your connection is full duplex.

Comment: @Nate, that is only a problem if you are writing MT code. Steer clear of that and it is not a serious problem at all.

Comment: True.  If you use the DataReceived event it is multi-threaded.  Also, if a user clicks a button and you send a command you are in the GUI thread.  I wouldn't want to block the GUI by calling Read all the time in the GUI thread (in the case of a polling protocol).  An app with a high data rate will almost always be multi-threaded, be it through GUI syncing, BackgroundWorkers, or a data parsing thread.  Once you understand the lock model it's really no big deal to just protect reads and writes.

Comment: Link to article is broken :(

Answer (score 3):

The .NET framework even has a proper [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx), which will be just fine for your application.