# Setting Serial Port from separate form C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need to pass a serial port from one form to another and i am having trouble setting the port after I use it in another form.
I have searched high and low for this answer but I may just not be understanding other answers to this problem. I know exactly what the problem is that I'm having I just can figure out how to fix it. I'm new to C# but have a decent background with C++. In C++ I would just pass by reference to fix this problem.Which I tried but to no avail

```
//In Form 2     
private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isConnected)
    {
        form1.unmountArduino();
    }
    else
    {
        portF2 = form1.borrowPort();
        bool success = form1.mountArduino(ComCombo.Text,portF2);
        if (success)
        {
            this.Close(); //If we connect close the form
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit(); //If it fails just close application for now 
        }
    }
}

// In form 1
public bool mountArduino(string selectedPort, SerialPort port)
{

    try
    {

        port = new SerialPort(selectedPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        port.Open();
        isConnected = port.IsOpen;
        port.Write("#STAR\n");  //This Command Writes just fine
        returnPort(port);      // Setter Function
        return true;

    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to Connect to COM Port");
        return false;
    }

}
public SerialPort borrowPort()
{
    return port;
}
public void returnPort(SerialPort usedPort)
{
    this.port = usedPort;
}
private void stepForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    port.Write("#FO"+stepBox.Text+"\n"); // Here is where I get my error
                                         //Exception: (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)
}
```

All of this code works great no problem except when I try to click a button on my form and send another command through the serial port. Then it says the port is out of scope and is null. Which makes sense because I made the port in a function but **in my mind the setter function should have taken care of it.**
Thanks for your help in advance I have looked everywhere but cant seem to find an exact answer to why the setter function is not working.

Comment: This may help: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/110670/Improving-the-Performance-of-Serial-Ports-Using-C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from and Sending data to Serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783591/reading-from-and-sending-data-to-serial-port)

Comment: This isnt really about Reading and Sending data, that part is fine its passing serial objects between forms

Comment: For clarification, the step forward button is clicked after connect right? And a new instance of Form 1 is not created? As in both these cases port will be null.

Comment: "Then it says the port is out of scope and is null" means what? The first sounds like a compile error, the seciond is a runtime error. Which is it

Comment: @cameroony, the reference i post have a complete configuration/sending/reading data with source code and Gui. Have a look to the method: `SendMessageThread()`,

Comment: Its a runtime error not compiler error the form is the same, Im running a stepper motor thats why the button is step forward...